# how to kill (or avoid) zombie processes with subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

When I kick off a python script from within another python script using the subprocess module, a zombie process is created when the subprocess "completes". I am unable to kill this subprocess unless I kill my parent python process.

Is there a way to kill the subprocess without killing the parent? I know I can do this by using wait(), but I need to run my script with no_wait().

Answer (score 31):

A zombie process is not a real process; it's just a remaining entry in the process table until the parent process requests the child's return code. The actual process has ended and requires no other resources but said process table entry.

We probably need more information about the processes you run in order to actually help more.

However, in the case that your Python program *knows* when the child processes have ended (e.g. by reaching the end of the child stdout data), then you can safely call `process.wait()`:

```
import subprocess

process= subprocess.Popen( ('ls', '-l', '/tmp'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in process.stdout:
        pass

subprocess.call( ('ps', '-l') )
process.wait()
print("after wait")
subprocess.call( ('ps', '-l') )
```

Example output:

```
$ python so2760652.py
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S   501 21328 21326  0  80   0 -  1574 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 S   501 21516 21328  0  80   0 -  1434 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 python
0 Z   501 21517 21516  0  80   0 -     0 exit   pts/2    00:00:00 ls <defunct>
0 R   501 21518 21516  0  80   0 -   608 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps
after wait
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S   501 21328 21326  0  80   0 -  1574 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 S   501 21516 21328  0  80   0 -  1467 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 python
0 R   501 21519 21516  0  80   0 -   608 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

Otherwise, you can keep all the children in a list, and now and then `.poll` for their return codes. After every iteration, remember to remove from the list the children with return codes different than `None` (i.e. the finished ones).

Comment: Oh, I see now that my answer is basically the code version of your last paragraph.

Comment: Very useful information about the zombie processes. Do you know if this information applies equally to all platforms? i.e. that zombie processes are merely entries and are not actually running.

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic: [zombie process](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html) is a real thing in POSIX: *A process that has terminated and that is deleted when its exit status has been reported to another process which is waiting for that process to terminate.*

Answer (score 23):

Not using `Popen.communicate()` or `call()` will result in a zombie process.

If you don't need the output of the command, you can use `subprocess.call()`:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['grep', 'jdoe', '/etc/passwd'])
0
```

If the output is important, you should use `Popen()` and `communicate()` to get the stdout and stderr.

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> process = Popen(['ls', '-l', '/tmp'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>>> stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
>>> stderr
''
>>> print stdout
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 jdoe jdoe 0 2010-05-03 17:05 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 jdoe jdoe 0 2010-05-03 17:05 baz
-rw-r--r-- 1 jdoe jdoe 0 2010-05-03 17:05 foo
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unforuntately, communicate waits for processes to complete before spawning a new one. I need to run numberous processes in parallel.

Comment: call() waits for the process to finish. I think the OP wants to spawn processes and do something else in the parent process while they run.

Comment: With `Popen.poll()` you can check if the process has finished, then you can use `communicate`. This way you can keep the concurrency.

Comment: What if you can't call `call` because you need to write to stdin of the process, but you don't care about the output?

Comment: A note, if you use the output of Popen in any way then the zombie process is still created.

Comment: If you you use communicate instead of wait... can you still retrieve the return code?

Answer (score 17):

If you delete the subprocess object, using **del** to force garbage collection, that will cause the subprocess object to be deleted and then the defunct processes will go away without terminating your interpreter.  You can try this out in the python command line interface first.

Comment: This didn't work for me: `s = subprocess.Popen('exec cat /dev/zero > /dev/null')`, then `killall cat` then `del s` → zombie is still there.

Comment: It worked for me. In Celery, when the SoftTimeLimitExceeded exception is raised, I call `s.kill()` then `del s`. No zombie.

Comment: This doesn't work on [Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760652/how-to-kill-or-avoid-zombie-processes-with-subprocess-module#comment29817645_6236440)

Answer (score 7):

If you simply use `subprocess.Popen`, you'll be fine - here's how:

```
import subprocess

def spawn_some_children():
    subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "3"])
    subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "3"])
    subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "3"])

def do_some_stuff():
    spawn_some_children()
    # do some stuff
    print "children went out to play, now I can do my job..."
    # do more stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_some_stuff()
```

You can use `.poll()` on the object returned by Popen to check whether it finished (without waiting). If it returns `None`, the child is still running.

Make sure you don't keep references to the Popen objects - if you do, they will not be garbage collected, so you end up with zombies. Here's an example:

```
import subprocess

def spawn_some_children():
    children = []
    children.append(subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "3"]))
    children.append(subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "3"]))
    children.append(subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "3"]))
    return children

def do_some_stuff():
    children = spawn_some_children()
    # do some stuff
    print "children went out to play, now I can do my job..."
    # do more stuff

    # if children finish while we are in this function,
    # they will become zombies - because we keep a reference to them
```

In the above example, if you want to get rid of the zombies, you can either `.wait()` on each of the children or `.poll()` until the result is not `None`.

**Either way is fine - either not keeping references, or using `.wait()` or `.poll()`.**

Comment: [have you checked that your first example doesn't produces zombies if parent is kept alive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760652/how-to-kill-or-avoid-zombie-processes-with-subprocess-module#comment29817645_6236440)

Comment: Awesome answer! Freeing the references to the killed process worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

The python runtime takes responsibility for getting rid of zombie process once their process objects have been garbage collected. If you see the zombie lying around it means you have kept a process object and not called wait, poll or terminate on it.

Comment: [A simple test shows that it is not true on Python 2](https://gist.github.com/zed/7504999). It seems to work on Python 3

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Are you sure that test is right?  Since you're not calling `.wait()`, `.poll()` or `.terminate()`, my guess is that Peter is correct.

Comment: @blong: to call a method, you need a name (or some other way to reference an object): the test intentionally does not keep explicit references to `Popen()` objects. It tests whether *"python runtime takes responsibility for getting rid of zombie process once their process objects have been garbage collected"*. There is some support for dealing with zombies: `_active` list, `_cleanup()` function is called from `Popen()` but the test shows that it doesn't help on Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean "I need to run my script with no_wait()", but I think this example does what you need. Processes will not be zombies for very long.  The parent process will only `wait()` on them when they are actually already terminated and thus they will quickly unzombify.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
import subprocess
import sys
import time

children = []
#Step 1: Launch all the children asynchronously
for i in range(10):
    #For testing, launch a subshell that will sleep various times
    popen = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep %s" % (i + 8)])
    children.append(popen)
    print "launched subprocess PID %s" % popen.pid

#reverse the list just to prove we wait on children in the order they finish,
#not necessarily the order they start
children.reverse()
#Step 2: loop until all children are terminated
while children:
    #Step 3: poll all active children in order
    children[:] = [child for child in children if child.poll() is None]
    print "Still running: %s" % [popen.pid for popen in children]
    time.sleep(1)

print "All children terminated"
```

The output towards the end looks like this:

```
Still running: [29776, 29774, 29772]
Still running: [29776, 29774]
Still running: [29776]
Still running: []
All children terminated
```

Comment: This is overkill. As Peter says - it's enough to make sure you're not keeping any reference to the Popen object and it will be taken care of. You only need to use poll() or wait() if you actually want to wait for the child processes to finish - which is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Also - if you *do* want to wait for the child processes to finish, you can just use wait() on each of them - you don't need to poll() and remove them from your list. Doing a wait() on each ensures that you are waiting until the last one has finished (if that is what you want).

Comment: @ibz: 1. [It is not enough to avoid keeping references to Popen objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760652/how-to-kill-or-avoid-zombie-processes-with-subprocess-module/2792898#comment29817645_6236440) 2. [Using `.wait()` might create zombies](https://gist.github.com/7505372): imagine you've called `.wait()` on a process that should terminate in an hour and you have other 1000 children that should exit in a second. boom. you've got 1000 zombies in a second that won't be reaped until the hour passes.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
s = Popen(args) 
s.terminate() 
time.sleep(0.5)
s.poll()
```

Zombie processes will disappear

Comment: Can you add relevant explanation/documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by `no_wait()`.  Do you mean you can't block waiting for child processes to finish?  Assuming so, I think this will do what you want:

```
os.wait3(os.WNOHANG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I came across this zombie problem due to my python script. The actual problem was mainly due to killing of the subprocess and the parent process doesn't know that the child is dead. So what I did was, just adding popen.communicate() after the kill signal of child process so that the parent process comes to know that the child is dead, then the kernel updates the pid of the childprocess since the child is no more and so there is no zombies formed now.

PS:poll is also an option here since it checks and conveys about the child status to the parent. Often in subprocess it is better if u use check_output or call if u need not communicate with the stdout and stdin.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't need to wait for any subprocesses you spawned, the simplest solution to prevent zombie processes is to call `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);` during initialization. Then, terminated subprocesses [are deleted immediately](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zombie-processes-prevention/). This setting applies to the whole process, so you can only use it if there isn't any child you need to wait for.

In Python:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)
# …
# call subprocess.Popen(…) as needed
```

Comment: Trying this w/in Django throws an error saying this method can be used only inside the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution:

os.killpg(os.getpgid(process.pid), signal.SIGINT)

And this command to verify the status my command:

ps auxww |grep $mycommand