# How to cleanly kill subprocesses in python

Tags: python, linux, zombie-process, defunct

We are using a python process to manage long running python subprocesses. Subprocesses occasionally need to be killed. The kill command does not completely kill the process, only makes it defunct.

Running the following script demonstrates this behaviour.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '400'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
```

or

```
p = subprocess.Popen('sleep 400', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Will create a subprocess.

```
p.terminate() 
p.kill()
```

does nothing to the process. Demonstrated by `ps aux | grep sleep`

```
$ ps aux| grep 'sleep'
User       8062  0.0  0.0   7292   764 pts/7    S    14:53   0:00 sleep 400
```

The process has not been killed/made defunct. Using the `subprocess.call()` function with `'kill'` and `pid` as arguments will issue the kill command.

```
subprocess.call(['kill', str(p.pid)])
```

This will kill the process but it is now defunct.

```
$ ps aux | grep 'sleep'
User       8062  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/7    Z+   14:51   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
```

If the queue is running long enough will it eventually reach its maximum number of processes, or will it eventually reap the defunct processes and be fine?

If the answer is the former, how can I handle defunct processes in python without killing the parent process?

Is there a better way of killing processes?

Comment: `kill` only sends a "signal" to the process and asks it to terminate it work. If you however `kill` it with `-9` it is killed by the operating system. But this is considered a bad way to end a process.

Comment: `kill -9` does the same thing as the `subprocess.kill()` function. Whether I try to terminate it cleanly with `p.terminate()` or kill it with `p.kill()` it still ends up as a zombie process.

Comment: I use `Popen.(['ffmpeg' etc...])` to save UDP data from localhost into an `mp3` file. When I end execution through the IDE everything works fine, but when I try to end it through the code itself with `Popen.terminate()` and `Popen.wait()` the file size is `zero`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are 2 main issues here:

First issue: If you're using `shell=True`, so you're killing the *shell* running the process, not the process itself. With its parent killed, the child process goes defunct / isn't killed immediately.

In your case, you're using `sleep` which is not built-in, so you could drop `shell=True`, and `Popen` would yield the actual process id: `p.terminate()` would work.

You can (and you should) avoid `shell=True` most of the time, even if it requires extra python coding effort (piping 2 commands together, redirecting input/output, all those cases can be nicely handled by one or several `Popen` *without* `shell=True`.

And (second issue) if the process is still defunct when terminating after that fix, you could call `p.wait()` (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760652/how-to-kill-or-avoid-zombie-processes-with-subprocess-module) question). Seems that calling `terminate` isn't enough. The `Popen` object needs to be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks, `p.wait()` after the `p.terminate()` call fixed it!

Comment: just for my information, can you try with `shell=True` to see if it still works? or if you get a defunct?

Comment: With shell=True the `ps aux | grep sleep` behaves as follows:

`User       9689  0.0  0.0   4508   796 pts/7    S+   16:28   0:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 100
User       9690  0.0  0.0   7292   648 pts/7    S+   16:28   0:00 sleep 100`

then issue the `p.kill()` or `p.terminate()` command.

`$ ps aux| grep 'sleep'
User       9690  0.0  0.0   7292   648 pts/7    S+   16:28   0:00 sleep 100`

Comment: No I don't think that will work. There is still a `sleep` process running after issuing the `p.terminate()` command, the kill command has killed the shell command (i think!)

Comment: Is there something else going on? I use `Popen.(['ffmpeg' etc...])` to save UDP data from localhost into an `mp3` file. When I end execution through the IDE everything works fine, but when I try to end it through the code itself with `Popen.terminate()` and `Popen.wait()` the file size is `zero`.

Comment: it seems that it should be another question.

Answer (score 8):

you should call `p.wait()` after terminating child process - for clearing process table. That should remove zombie processes (in `defunct` state)

Comment: that fixes the issue (so +1) but only if `shell=False`.

Comment: agree, shell=False required, so there is no shell spawned by python and it calls clone/exec directly