# Close appication window on screen opened by subprocess (not only the internal subprocess)

Tags: python

I need to open and close a application on a Windows machine using Python. I tried (opening the calculator):

```
import subprocess, time
p = subprocess.Popen(["calc"])
time.sleep(2)
p.terminate()
```

also using

```
p.kill()
```

does not work.

However, it seems that while the (python internal) subprocess is terminated, the application still remains visible on the screen (the calculator window does not close).

How can I open and close some application (including the actual visible window)?

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

Comment: Not a windows user, but since you are using pid. Try p.kill() might work.

Comment: `p.kill` does not close the window, regardless if opened with `shell=True` argument or not.

Comment: A `p.wait()` after `p.terminate()` may also help. Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961430/how-to-cleanly-kill-subprocesses-in-python

Comment: No does not work either, I checkt the `p.wait()` command as well. This is why I'm puzzled, nothing seen elsewhere worked so far. `p.wait()` seems to ensure clean termination of the (internal) process, but visible window is unaffected (on my machines)

Comment: try ```os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)``` or ```os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)```

Comment: Sorry for asking to just try stuff. . . I do remember I dealt with something like this a long time ago. It wasn't a hard solution. But can't pinpoint. :)

Comment: I also tried with `import signal` `signal.SIGTERM` but no success. Your line throws an error "an integer is required (got type SubprocessPopen)"

Comment: I tried `os.system("taskkill /f /im Calculator.exe")` and it successfully closes the task with the corresponding name... It might be a good starting point to generalize it using the child process pid...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to close the window in the foreground using the `win32` library:

```
import subprocess, time
import win32gui, win32con

for x in range(2):
    # Open calculator
    p = subprocess.Popen(["calc"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    time.sleep(3)
    # Terminate subprocess
    p.terminate() 
    # Close window in foreground unsing win32
    handler = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    win32gui.PostMessage(handler,win32con.WM_CLOSE,0,0)
    time.sleep(3)
```