# how can i kill all the zombie process on my computer?

Tags: python, zombie-process

i am trying to find a running process by it's but zombie process interrupt me- because of it i can't Determine if the process itself is running.

```
for pid in psutil.pids():
    try:
        p = psutil.Process(pid)
        if name in p.name():
            return True
        else:
            pass
    except:
        return Fals
```

Comment: Look this question,it will give an answer what your looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760652/how-to-kill-or-avoid-zombie-processes-with-subprocess-module#

Answer (score 0):

**However what you can do,**

- You need to .join() on your processes in a worker Queue, which will lock them to the calling application until all of them succeed or kill when the parent is killed, and run them in daemon mode.
- Check the parent joins its children, to avoid zombies. Check this out, it might give some insight about [multiprocessing in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process)
- You can check whether a child is still running with the is_alive() member function.