# Python 3 : subprocess causes zombies

Tags: python, subprocess, zombie-process

Following [the popular answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760652/how-to-kill-or-avoid-zombie-processes-with-subprocess-module) and the instructions [here](http://pythonforengineers.com/chapter-8-python-vs-zombies/) I created the code below in python 3:

```
  p1                = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "-e", "-o", "pcpu,args"],           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  p2                = subprocess.Popen(["cut", "-c", "-132"],   stdin=p1.stdout,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  p3                = subprocess.Popen(["awk", "NR>2"],         stdin=p2.stdout,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  p4                = subprocess.Popen(["sort", "-nr"],         stdin=p3.stdout,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  p5                = subprocess.Popen(["head", "-10"],         stdin=p4.stdout,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  ps,err            = p5.communicate()
  psout             = str(ps, 'utf-8')
```

This code is called every minute or so in a loop. Contrary to what I was led to believe this still creates zombies.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The zombies when running the code:

```
$ ps -eo pid,ppid,state,cmd | awk '$3 == "Z"'
14441 11232 Z [ps] <defunct>
14442 11232 Z [cut] <defunct>
14445 11232 Z [sort] <defunct>
```

Comment: Add the relevant `ps` output too.

Comment: Ummm...I actually meant the relevant zombie (`Z`) processes. Here `ps -eo pid,ppid,state,cmd | awk '$3 == "Z"'`

Comment: Ahum. My bad. Changed the latest edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `communicate()` for all subprocesses to get rid of 'defunct' processes.