How to clear task resources and zombie processes
I am building celery + django + selenium application. I am running selenium-based browsers in separate processes with help celery. Versions:
celery==5.2.6
redis==3.4.1
selenium-wire==5.1.0
Django==4.0.4
djangorestframework==3.13.1

I found out that after several hours application generates thousands of zombie processes. Also found out that problem deals with celery docker container, because after sudo /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /data/new_app/docker-compose.yml restart celery I have 0 zombie processes.
My code
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['POST'])
def periodic_check_all_urls(request): # web-service endpoint
    ...
    check_urls.delay(parsing_results_ids) # call celery task


Celery task code
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task()
def check_urls(parsing_result_ids: List[int]):
    """
    Run Selenium-based parser
    the parser exctracts data and saves in database
    """
    try:
        logger.info(f"{datetime.now()} Start check_urls")
        parser = Parser() # open selenium browser
        parsing_results = ParsingResult.objects.filter(pk__in=parsing_result_ids).exclude(status__in=["DONE", "FAILED"])
        parser.check_parsing_result(parsing_results)
    except Exception as e:
        full_trace = traceback.format_exc()
    finally:
        if 'parser' in locals():
            parser.stop()


Selenium browser stop function and destructor
class Parser():
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Prepare parser
        """
        if not USE_GUI:
            self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
            self.display.start()
        

        """ Replaced with FireFox
        self.driver = get_chromedriver(proxy_data)
        """
        proxy_data = {
            ...
        }
        self.driver = get_firefox_driver(proxy_data=proxy_data)

    
    def __del__(self):
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        try:
            self.driver.quit()
            logger.info("Selenium driver closed")
        except:
            pass
        
        try:
            self.display.stop()
            logger.info("Display stopped")
        except:
            pass

Also I was trying several settings to limit celery task resources and time of work (it didn't help with Zombie processes)
My celery settings in dgango settings.py
# celery setting (documents generation)
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER", "redis://redis:6379/0")
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER", "redis://redis:6379/0")
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("core_app.celery",)
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 10 * 60

My celery settings in dockers
celery:
    build: ./project
    command: celery -A core_app worker  --loglevel=info --concurrency=15 --max-memory-per-child=1000000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
      - ./project/media:/project/media
      - ./project/logs:/project/logs
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
    # environment variables declared in the environment section override env_file
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis

I read Django/Celery - How to kill a celery task? but it didn't help
Also read Celery revoke leaving zombie ffmpeg process but my task already contains try/except
Example of zombie processes
ps aux | grep 'Z'

root     32448  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:45   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>
root     32449  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:09   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>
root     32450  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    11:13   0:00 [sh] <defunct>
root     32451  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:44   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>
root     32452  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    10:12   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>
root     32453  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:52   0:00 [sh] <defunct>
root     32454  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    10:40   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>
root     32455  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:52   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>
root     32456  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    10:13   0:00 [sh] <defunct>
root     32457  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    10:51   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>
root     32459  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    14:01   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>
root     32460  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:16   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>
root     32461  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    10:40   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>
root     32462  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    10:12   0:00 [Utility Process] <defunct>


Did you try the solution of calling return after parser.stop() in your Celery task code from the 2nd last link? Also I don't think limiting task resources would prevent zombie processes?

@keventhen4 will try to call return, why do you think that is can help? I think that end of function is similar to retur None

Sorry, I read it wrong, return is just for making sure the process has ended, and default end of function does indeed seem to return None. I believe Celery has a wait() equivalent to get rid of zombie processes? Solution is probably similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2760652/16169432

Please modify your stop method to @Apex862-2's answer, and show us the log data of the traceback

Use timeout and soft_time_limit
You have already set CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT, but it can be beneficial to also use soft_time_limit. The soft_time_limit sends a TimeoutError signal to the task, which you can catch to clean up resources before the task is forcefully terminated after the time_limit.
Here’s how you can set both:
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded

@shared_task(soft_time_limit=600, time_limit=650)
def check_urls(parsing_result_ids: List[int]):
    try:
        logger.info(f"{datetime.now()} Start check_urls")
        parser = Parser()  # Open selenium browser
        parsing_results = ParsingResult.objects.filter(pk__in=parsing_result_ids).exclude(status__in=["DONE", "FAILED"])
        parser.check_parsing_result(parsing_results)
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        logger.warning(f"Task exceeded soft time limit, cleaning up resources.")
    except Exception as e:
        full_trace = traceback.format_exc()
        logger.error(f"Error occurred: {full_trace}")
    finally:
        if 'parser' in locals():
            parser.stop()

Ensure All Selenium Processes are Cleaned
Make sure all subprocesses, including the Selenium driver and X server (in headless mode), are correctly stopped. This could involve adding explicit process killing if necessary. For instance:
import psutil
import os

class Parser():
    def __init__(self):
        if not USE_GUI:
            self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
            self.display.start()

        self.driver = get_firefox_driver(proxy_data=proxy_data)

    def stop(self):
        try:
            self.driver.quit()
            logger.info("Selenium driver closed")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error closing driver: {e}")
        
        try:
            self.display.stop()
            logger.info("Display stopped")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error stopping display: {e}")

        # Clean up any remaining subprocesses (especially related to Selenium)
        self.cleanup_selenium_processes()

    def cleanup_selenium_processes(self):
        # Check for any lingering Selenium processes
        for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
            try:
                if 'selenium' in proc.info['name'].lower():
                    logger.info(f"Killing zombie process: {proc.info['pid']}")
                    proc.terminate()
            except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
                pass



Implement soft_time_limit and time_limit for task termination.
Ensure that all Selenium resources are released (including driver and display).
Use psutil to clean  lingering processes.
Configure Docker  memory limits and restart policies.
Use max-tasks-per-child to automatically restart workers.

Added time limits and cleanup_selenium_processes but it didn't help. I see 27000 zombie processes

I'd start by turning the Parser class into a context manager:
class Parser():
    def __init__(self):
        self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
        self.display.start()
        self.driver = get_firefox_driver(proxy_data={})

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.driver

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.kill_driver()
        self.display.stop()
        # handle exceptions here
        # if this returns true, any exceptions will be supressed

    def kill_driver(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()

If there is an error thrown within the with block, Parser.__exit__ will be called before the exception is raised, which gives you the chance to kill the driver and the display before the process closes.
Note that I removed your empty try: except: blocks in the stop method.  This is bad practice, because you won't see the traceback, which would be quite useful for debugging your question...
Now in your task:
@shared_task()
def check_urls(parsing_result_ids):
    with Parser() as parser:
        parsing_results = ParsingResult.objects.filter(pk__in=parsing_result_ids).exclude(status__in=["DONE", "FAILED"])
        parser.check_parsing_result(parsing_results)

It's unlikely Celery is the problem.  Using Selenium within a Docker container seems to be the root cause of the zombie processes.  See Jimmy Engelbrecht's answer for further details.
Jimmy's solution to the zombie problem:
def quit_driver_and_reap_children(driver):
    log.debug('Quitting session: %s' % driver.session_id)
    driver.quit()
    try:
        pid = True
        while pid:
            pid = os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)
            log.debug("Reaped child: %s" % str(pid))

            #Wonka's Solution to avoid infinite loop cause pid value -> (0, 0)
            try:
                if pid[0] == 0:
                    pid = False
            except:
                pass
            #---- ----

    except ChildProcessError:
        pass

If this solution doesn't work, please show us the traceback you suppressed in your Parser.stop method.

Thank you, checking this approach
